# Filter out any XSS code in ASP Web API models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a rather complex asp.net web API and I'd like to globally filter through any strings that are passed into the web api and filter out any XSS code.

I'm planning to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXss/

```
HtmlSantizationLibrary.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(someHtmlString);
```

So I'm mostly concerned to come up with a **global solution** here. I **don't want to manually call** the GetSafeHtmlFragment() everywhere individually, but apply it globally to all incoming strings!

I've looked into **ModelBinders** but could work out a good solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could also use a custome filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I try to bring up a solution/starting point.

First you need to know how to register your filter. My assumation is, you want to check every request:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AntiXssFilter());
```

Now, you have to create a filter that checks the request.
I do not know exactly what kind of data you have, but this should be a starting point:

```
public class AntiXssFilter: FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
       // check your request for any xss violations.
       // e.g. request.InputStream

    }
}
```